# Can't access the EC2 instance remotely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I'm trying to connect my friend's MySQL database remotely but I'm getting connection timeout error. I tried to ssh. But same result.

Then I check that instance. It has public IP. Also allowed 3306 and 22 ports on the security group. Allowed 100th rule for all sources in subnet NACL.

What I'm missing? Is there any other way to block those traffic? Can anyone help me? I'm a still beginner

Comment: Could you provide some pictures of your instance configuration as well as the security group inbound/outbound settings?

Comment: Typically, it is best to leave all NACL rules at their default "Allow All" setting unless you have a very specific need (eg creating a DMZ).

Comment: I presume that the MySQL database is running on an Amazon EC2 instance? Is your friend able to connect to it 'remotely' too? Can either of you successfully SSH into the EC2 instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No, my friend also can't access it remotely. Only both of us can access within the vpc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. That instance was deployed in a private subnet and didn't have inbound access.

Solution:-
I deployed a bastion host in a public subnet and used SSH agent forwarding to access the instance through the bastion host.

Answer (score 0):

When an SSH connection times-out, it is normally an indication that network traffic is not getting to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)

Based on your descriptions, I would suggest checking whether the instance was launched in a **public subnet**.